# jQuery UI slider to resize image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to make a jQuery UI slider wich resize my image size.
However the image size is never the same so I would like to resize with percentage respecting the ratio.
Here is what I've done so far : http://jsfiddle.net/Au3kk/

I tried this but it doesn't work on the event :

```
 width :  ($(this).css('width')) + (ui.value + "%");
```

I'm new with Javascript I hope you won't be to hard with me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing off the original width:

```
var orginalWidth = $("#image").width();
```

And then using:

```
$("#image").width(orginalWidth * (1 + ui.value/100));
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PrLv9/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is what I was looking for.
I just don't understand why width() resize the height as well. Anyway it works! thanks

Comment: @casusbelli - You're welcome. I noticed that about the height resizing. Is that something you want or don't want?

Comment: Well, your code works as I want. I was wondering how come the method width() change the **height()** value of my image as well.I Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @casusbelli - I understand, and I think I know the answer now. Since you are not specifying the "height" attribute on the `<img>` element, its value defaults to "auto". That means it will preserve the aspect ratio of the image when the width is changed. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrLv9/3/) that sets the "height" so it is not "auto".

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify this line, from

---

`$("#image").css({
          width :  ($(this).css('width')) + (ui.value + "%");
      });`

---

to

```
 $('#image').css('width',ui.value+'%');
```

---

if you remove the last part of the command ( +'%' ) the image will resize in pixels.
Please note that the value of a percentage increase must be greater than 0(where 0 means invisible) however it can go above 100%. In your example you have set minimum to -50 and maximum to 50.

Also with the command `$(this).css` , you tried to read the css of the element where events are triggered (slider in this instance) instead of the actual image css