# img height as a percentage of the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to make a full-width picture slider with jquery (myself) and i want it to scale well in any size of the browser in a way that its height is smth like 80% of the browser window's height and resizes as the browser do indeed!
this is my html:

```
<body>
<img class="img_slides" src="../images/1.jpg" alt="1.jpg" width="90%"/> 
</body>
```

but it doesn't work while if i use width insteed of height the exact thing i want happens!
sry if i wrote too much! but otherwise my question wasnt meeting the sites qualities and they couldn't submit it!!

Comment: You want height to be 80%, how about width? auto?

Comment: Writing as much as needed is not a problem, in itself, quality-wise. In fact, I'd appreciate writing just a tiny bit *more*, in this case. (Specifically: is there any difference with the jQ slider actually on? Or would solving the pure HTML + CSS part be enough?)

Anyway, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245752/jquery-ui-slider-to-resize-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642866/height-percentage-not-working-in-css

Comment: oh yeah the last question is the same problem i had:)i'm sry for my spam then! i really tried my best to find the question but couldnt!thanks anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Codepen e.g.](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/full/xGyaKg)

```
img {
    height: 80%;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

You need to have `body & html` `height` set to `100%` because by default they don't take 100% of the viewport. Without it, setting image's `height` to `80%` won't work.

Comment: but i want to adjust the heights in my html not in the css(sb told it help for better faster loading)

Answer (score 3):

This should auto-size your image and center it on the page

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="#">
</div>


<style type="text/css">
  .wrapper {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
  .image {position:absolute; height: 80%; width:auto; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; margin:auto}
</style>
```

// EDIT

```
<body style="width:100%; height:100; margin:0">
  <img class="image" style="position: absolute; height: 80%; width: auto; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;" src="url.jpg">
</body>
```

Comment: you can set the `<body>` element to 100% w/h instead, I usually use a div as a wrapper but the body element should work also. P.S you can set `margin: 0` on the `<body>` to get edge to edge fill

Comment: then, if i set the height in my html attributes, it doesnt work and i dont want to put width and heights in css

Comment: yeah it works! but its still not what i exactly wanted!thank you anyways:)